# how create th element dynamicly

Tags: html, laravel, eloquent

hi i want to know how to build table column dynamically increased based on the numbers of date period or days that come from two date picker input value and placed the date as the header of the column. i use this to filter data from DB to build attendance sample.
the following is the code to create table header cell but using button

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr id="myTr">
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Click the button to create a TH element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("TH");
  var t = document.createTextNode("table header cell");
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("myTr").appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the following code how i get 2 date picker value but dont know how to calculate the period between those value and how to inject it as logic inwhich the column increased

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>A demonstration of how to access a Date field</h3>

<input type="date" id="startdate" value="2014-02-09">
<br>
<input type="date" id="enddate" value="2014-02-09">

<p>Click the button to get the date of the date field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> input elements with type="date" do not show as any date field/calendar in IE 11 and earlier versions.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
<br>
<p id="demo1"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("startdate").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  var x = document.getElementById("enddate").value;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

thank you inadvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to make ease to work with dates, getDates is a functions to return an array with the dates between the inputs.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var startDate = document.getElementById("startdate").value;
  var endDate = document.getElementById("enddate").value;


  var dates = getDates(startDate, endDate);

  var thead = document.querySelector('#myTable thead');
  thead.innerHTML = ''

  for (const date of dates) {
    var x = document.createElement("th");
    var t = document.createTextNode(date);
    x.appendChild(t);
    thead.appendChild(x);
  }
}

function getDates(startDate, endDate) {
  var dateArray = [];
  var currentDate = moment(startDate);
  var stopDate = moment(endDate);
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    dateArray.push(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
  }
  return dateArray;
}
```

```css
table,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="startdate" value="2019-02-09">
<br>
<input type="date" id="enddate" value="2019-02-09">
<p>Click the button to get the date of the date field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you @Hans C. Felix Ramos exactly i work with laravel to build attendance system and by the question above i want to fetch data from timestamp field and display it within the cell table below the header according to date within the header would you like to suggest me how do i must work with this idea. up to now i already built the concept but only with single column to display timestamp with various dates. for short i want to filter presents status of several users and displayed within cell based on dates of the column header. thank you in advance